# read a file and save the content of a row and column and save it as a variable in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile

I generate a file by extracting information from diffeent files and saving the data on each file to a line in the generated file . Then i read the file into my program and display it in QTableview. I created a QItemdelegate that adds a button to each row in my Qtableview. So at the click of the each of the button, I want a QDialog to pop up which should read the content of the matching file from which the contents of that row was generated. The name of the file, which is the content of the variable is what I want the program to use in locating the file.

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
 {

     QStyleOptionButton button;
     QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
     int x,y,w,h;
     x = r.left() + r.width() - 70;//the X coordinate
     y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
     w = 70;//button width
     h = 30;//button height
     button.rect = QRect(x,y,w,h);
     button.text = "View log";
     button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;

     QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, painter);
 }

 bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
 {
     Q_UNUSED(model)
     if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
     {
         QMouseEvent * e = (QMouseEvent *)event;
         int clickX = e->x();
         int clickY = e->y();

         QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
         int x,y,w,h;
         x = r.left() + r.width() - 30;//the X coordinate
         y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
         w = 30;//button width
         h = 30;//button height

         if( clickX > x && clickX < x + w )
             if( clickY > y && clickY < y + h )
             {
                 int r = index.row(); // <---- row
                 int c = index.column(); // <---- column

                 QFile file("/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/jobSummary");
                 if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)) {

                     // file line counter
                     QTextStream in(&file); // read to text stream

                     while (!in.atEnd()) {

                         // read one line from textstream(separated by "\n")
                         QString fileLine = in.readLine();


                         // parse the read line into separate pieces(tokens) with "," as the delimiter
                         QStringList lineToken = fileLine.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

                         // load parsed data to model accordingly
                         if (lineToken.size() == 6)
                         {
                             for (int row=r; int column=0; column< 2; column++;)
                             {
                                 QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(lineToken[column]);
                                 //mytablemodel3->setItem(Max_Number_of_Lines, column, item);


                             }


                         }

                 QDialog * d = new QDialog();
                 d->setGeometry(300,0,100,100);
                 d->show();
                 d->setWindowTitle("Log viewer");
             }



             }
     }

     return true;
 }

 }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific whats the issue? where you need assistance?

Comment: What row and column do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to save the contents of the file in the item corresponding to the delegate you pressed? If so, do you want to save all the content or just part of the text? If it is a part of the text, how do you identify that part?

Comment: I generate a file by extracting information from different files and saving the data on each file to a line in the generated file . Then i read the file into my program and display it in QTableview. I created a QItemdelegate that adds a button to each row in my Qtableview. So at the click of the each of the button, I want a QDialog to pop up which should read the content of the matching file from which the contents of that row was generated. The name of the file, which is the content of the variable is what I want the program to use in locating the file.

Comment: The column will be the first column while the row is the row where the delegate button is located in the QTAbleview as this is same as the row where the content of the variable is located: A sample of a row in the file: naby-momoh-chad.depth_nabeelah.12,        4106, Running,         user12,                           Thu Jan 26 09:52:47 2017,             st--training2. The commas seperates each column

Comment: In what part of your program do you want to use that name that will be saved?

Comment: In the same function:

Comment: I understand that the text you want to save is lineToken [column]. Am I right? If so, where do you want to save it?

Comment: what function??

Comment: Do you want to save it in some QTableView item? If so, in which item, what are their coordinates?

Comment: I just want to save the text as a variable, then i want to use this variable to search for a file with the matching name as the content of the variable and then display that file in a QDialog. I will optimize the code now here

Comment: Why do you use QStandardItem?,that is what confuses me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Am really sorry, i was supposed to comment that out.

Comment: @BlavidaUbee Please do not just put code in your question, add the description you made in the comments in the content of your question.

Comment: @eyllanesc i tried to but it always gave an error requesting that the description was not there. Is there a special way of separating codes from comments. I am very new to this platform. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @BlavidaUbee If you are new you should take the time and read the links provided by the community such as [ask], [tour], [mcve], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the text that you are in the `r-th` row and before the first comma you just have to iterate over the `QTextStream` to locate row, then you separate the text according to the used separator, in your case the comma after you leave the loop.

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
 {

     QStyleOptionButton button;
     QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
     button.rect = QRect(r.topRight() - QPoint(70, 0), QSize(70, 30));
     button.text = "View log";
     button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;
     QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, painter);
 }

 bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
 {
    Q_UNUSED(model)
    if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
    {
        QMouseEvent * e = (QMouseEvent *)event;
        QPoint p = e->pos();

        QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
        QRect re(r.topRight() - QPoint(30, 0), QSize(30, 30));

        if(re.contains(p)){
            int r = index.row(); // <---- row
            int c = index.column(); // <---- column

            QString filename; // text of the first column and r-row

            QFile file("/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/jobSummary");
            int counter = 0;
            if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)) {
                QTextStream in(&file); // read to text stream
                while (!in.atEnd()) {
                    QString fileLine = in.readLine();
                    if(counter == r){
                        filename = fileLine.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts).first();
                        break;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            QDialog * d = new QDialog();
            d->setGeometry(300,0,100,100);
            d->show();
            d->setWindowTitle("Log viewer");
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, so how then do i display the content on the Qdialog. The folder part where the files are located is /home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/runninglogs/

Comment: @BlavidaUbee you must create a custom QDialog that contains a QTextEdit, or QPlainTextEdit where you can place the text. The QDialog by default does not have that feature

Comment: I know but the c++ to use the variable to search for a matching file in the folder is what I need, I have already created the dialog that pops up when the button is clicked, you can see it in the code. please help optimize the code to search for the file and display on the dialog. Thank you

Comment: @BlavidaUbee considering that the name of the file is in filename, and the directory is the one that you comment initially then the complete path is: `QString fullPath = QDir("/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/runninglogs/").filePath(filename);`

Comment: When i run the program, it still tells me the file doesn't exist, but it actually exists in the directory. Could you help with this

Comment: @BlavidaUbee print `fullPath`

Comment: @BlavidaUbee Do not edit my answer if it is not necessary.

Comment: sorry please i don't get, I have seen the `fullpath` and it is correct. Do i need to print `fullpath` within my program

Comment: sorry about that, taught i was editing the question to show you what my codes look like

Comment: @BlavidaUbee 
Then if the fullpath is correct, your file does not exist, verify that that file exists.